# ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed, Pillow Python3.9 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've tried desperately to make Python 3.9 work on my Pi but the last roadblock is Pillow failing to use its text libraries. It works just fine on my 3.7 install, but 3.9 won't work at all.

Here's my callback

```
Ignoring exception in command mon:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 167, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/koibot/koitools/pokedex.py", line 95, in mon
    await Pokédex.dexentry(self, ctx, mon)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/koibot/koitools/pokedex.py", line 674, in dexentry
    embed, f, f2, f3 = Pokédex.dexembedbuilder(self, ctx, mon, md, md["level"],movelist,md['sc'])
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/koibot/koitools/pokedex.py", line 613, in dexembedbuilder
    font = ImageFont.truetype(r"/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMono.ttf", 12)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 855, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 852, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 187, in __init__
    if core.HAVE_RAQM:
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 44, in __getattr__
    raise ImportError("The _imagingft C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

This is from a Discord bot that works just fine on 3.7 - the issue isn't connected to the discord lib I'm using, but is an error with an image the code generates using text. PIL seems to now be unable to process text due to some missing module.

Since 3.9 isn't available on Pi yet I had to install it manually from the tar. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pillow as well as making sure the libs (including and especially libfreetype6) are all up to date. Is it a PATH issue? Something else I don't know about?

Comment: What is your end-goal? Installing the python discord module for Python3.9?

Comment: This is from a Discord bot that works just fine on 3.7 - the issue isn't connected to the discord lib I'm using, but is an error with an image the code generates using text. PIL seems to now be unable to process text due to some missing module.

Comment: It might be useful to add that background information to your question so all the information is in context.